# How to allow access to a NextJS api route from a different domain?

Tags: next.js, cors, same-origin-policy

I have a NextJs with an `/api/revalidate` route for on-demand cache revalidation.

But I need to call this endpoint from a different domain and I'm getting the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'DOMAIN_1/api/revalidate' from origin 'DOMAIN_2' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How can I set up CORS on an API endpoint for a NextJS app?

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that NextJS has an example about setting up CORS in an API route:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-cors

And also you can use `nextjs-cors`, which is a wrapper on top of `cors`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-cors

The code will look something like this:

```
import NextCors from 'nextjs-cors';

async function handler(req, res) {
   // Run the cors middleware
   // nextjs-cors uses the cors package, so we invite you to check the documentation https://github.com/expressjs/cors
   await NextCors(req, res, {
      // Options
      methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
      origin: '*',
      optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
   });

   // Rest of the API logic
   res.json({ message: 'Hello NextJs Cors!' });
}
```